# Multipass accessing localhost

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, multipass

I am finding this very difficult to work with.

I have installed multipass on Ubuntu 20.04. Inside multipass I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 like this.

```
multipass launch -n ubuntu
```

Not inside multipass Ubuntu I am trying to test django app.

```
python manage.py runserver
November 26, 2020 - 05:56:05
Django version 3.1.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Now the question is, How do I access this link?

Multipass says:

```
System information as of Thu Nov 26 11:19:54 IST 2020
IPv4 address for ens4: 10.158.109.84
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to crack this with an obvious solution.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then clicking on `http://10.158.109.84:8000/` from the host computer browser worked.

However, I am yet to find a solution on how to access the development server from other computers on the network. If anyone has some Idea please answer and I will delete this.
Thanks.